# Multiple frontends, shared database, CDN

Tags: magento-1.9, database, configuration, hosting, multiple

I would like to set up a Magento server and one of the goals will be to reliably serve China. Let's just say I'm not going to engage a CDN.

I have one frontend and backend connecting to a database in asia.
Is it possible to host a frontend in China that connects to this very same database?

I have considered the following:
 1. Two servers with their own instances of memcached connecting to the same database.
 2. Two servers sharing one instance of memcached connecting to the database.

If someone places an order on the second server, how would it trigger processing on the first if my intention is to let the first server do the crunching.

Hypothetically, this wouldn't be much different from running a backend on a different server from the frontend which I've heard is doable, so would it be safe to assume that backend processes are triggered by cron?
Is it possible to manage two frontends with a single backend?
How would extensions be affected?

My understanding of all this is quite vague so bear with me if I'm asking a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the Box, Magento supports multiple front end (websites) setup which you can configure in System -> Manage Stores.

You will be able to configure either of your two hosting environment setups, although you might need to speak to your web hosting provider for instructions on how to configure it properly.

If you have the database remotely, then when you install, or deploy your local.xml would need to set the hostname (or IP) of the database server. Likewise, the authentication settings on the actual database server would need to be configured to allow remote connections to mysql (port 3306 by default).

Comment: Sorry. I should clarify that one frontend is almost dedicated to serving content to China and therefore should be in that server in China.

If my chinese server receives orders, will it only process its own orders?
Or would it process both my Main and China orders?

Comment: Essentially, I'd like to set up another node.

Comment: The Chinese front end server can be setup to point to the remote database, so orders from both China and wherever else you are serving would be visible in the backend.

Comment: That makes sense. If the order is made in China, the Chinese server will process it? Emails and the such? How much transactional data will remain in the Chinese frontend?

Comment: You would configure translations etc at a theme level and attribute level, so transactional emails etc would (normally) be sent out by that specific web node. The rest will generally come from the database its self.